# В битрикс компоненте не работает редактирование и удаление?

Tags: битрикс

У меня почему то не работает панель редактирования и удаления. Это компонент у меня находится на двух страницах. На главной всплывает панелька удаления. А вот на другой странице не работает.Буду рад любой помощи!

```
 <?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */

$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>


<style>
    .image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 270px;
    border-radius: 5%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-size: cover;
    }
    
    .row{
    display: flex;
        }
</style>


<div class="row">

<?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
    <?
    $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
    $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
    ?>

    <div  class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4">

                      <div

                        data-element="d521c66d-ccef-46d2-8e89-426471254033/172387e8-156d-47c0-8481-10ae74ea9a54"
                        class="cli-goods-card big sale"
                      >
                        <!---->
                        <div
                          class="image-select cli-card-img"
                          data-element="d521c66d-ccef-46d2-8e89-426471254033/3cff3fdb-dc95-4592-a5cf-5b54e2d69784"
                          style="overflow: visible"
                        >
    <p class="item" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>"></p>
                        <? $arFile = CFile::GetFileArray($arItem["PROPERTIES"]["PHOTO"]["VALUE"]); ?>
                      <div class="image"  style="background-image:url(<?= $arFile["SRC"] ?>)"></div>

    
                          <!----><!---->
                        </div>
                        <h3
                          data-element="d521c66d-ccef-46d2-8e89-426471254033/d43349ed-6ab9-4f7e-9c27-04222d2b0f71"
                          data-design="73cb1ce2-fcb0-11ea-adc1-0242ac120002/d43349ed-6ab9-4f7e-9c27-04222d2b0f71"
                          class="mt-4 cli-name cli-title-3 cli-bold"
                        >
                                    <?=$arItem["NAME"] ?><br /><br
                            class="ProseMirror-trailingBreak"
                          />
                        </h3>
                        <h4
                          data-element="d521c66d-ccef-46d2-8e89-426471254033/00d45a8e-b79d-44cf-824b-1663397a5908"
                          data-design="73cb1ce2-fcb0-11ea-adc1-0242ac120002/00d45a8e-b79d-44cf-824b-1663397a5908"
                          class="cli-mod cli-caption"
                          style="display: none"
                        >
                          <br class="ProseMirror-trailingBreak" />
                        </h4>
                        <div   class="mb-2 cli-price cli-body-1">
                          <span
                            data-element="d521c66d-ccef-46d2-8e89-426471254033/5927e736-a4e7-42d9-b4fc-b9dc1ecb3841"
                            data-design="73cb1ce2-fcb0-11ea-adc1-0242ac120002/5927e736-a4e7-42d9-b4fc-b9dc1ecb3841"
                            class="cli-current-price "
                            style="color: rgb(255, 87, 34)"
                            ><?= $arItem["PROPERTIES"]["PRICE"]["VALUE"] ?></span
                          ><s
                            data-element="d521c66d-ccef-46d2-8e89-426471254033/98377a8c-b0aa-4530-a233-ad6ecb6ff7fe"
                            data-design="73cb1ce2-fcb0-11ea-adc1-0242ac120002/98377a8c-b0aa-4530-a233-ad6ecb6ff7fe"
                            class="cli-regular"
                            style="display: none"
                            ><br class="ProseMirror-trailingBreak"
                          /></s>
                        </div>
                        <a 
                          class="mb-4 cli-btn fixed primary middle" 
                          style="background-color: rgb(255, 87, 34)"
                          target="_self"
                          data-element="d521c66d-ccef-46d2-8e89-426471254033/4bd72fc2-c279-4af3-9d19-3609963f6677"
                          data-design="73cb1ce2-fcb0-11ea-adc1-0242ac120002/4bd72fc2-c279-4af3-9d19-3609963f6677"
                          data-popup=""
                          data-anchor=""
                          data-order='{"id":"73cb1ce2-fcb0-11ea-adc1-0242ac120002-4bd72fc2-c279-4af3-9d19-3609963f6677","name":"Тягач Sitrak 4х2 C7H мкпп","description":"","price":"819 000 ¥","quantity":1,"img":"/images/f3102a6eaf5f326427aa8705c869e92e.webp"}'
                          href="<?=$arItem["PROPERTIES"]["SRC_PAGE"]["VALUE"]?>"
                          ><!----><span class="cli-btn-text"
                            >Спецификация</span
                          ></a
                        >
                      </div>
                    </div>

<?endforeach?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Панель редактирования и удаления всплывает после того, как мышь оказывается над объектом, у которого `id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>"`. У вас таким объектом оказывается `<p>` без какого-либо содержимого. Я удивлён, что у вас панель вообще где-либо всплывает. Поставьте этот id у какого-либо объемлющего div. А то может получиться, ваш `<p></p>` просто не попадает под мышь.